# Why is my C++ Regular Expression not working?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Okay, so I am trying to learn c++ regular expressions and I am having some trouble with it. I went over the code, and at least to me, it makes logical sense. I also tested it online using a regex tester and it successfully matched my string. The first two(`nameParser`, and `anotherNameParser`) do NOT work, but the last one(`sampleParser`) does. I really do not understand why it is not validating my string. Below I included a screen shot:
[image: Screenshot showing output]

```
//http://rextester.com/tester
//compile with g++ -std=gnu++11 main.cpp -o main
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

/* * (nameParser)
 * Beginning at the front of the string, any set of character followed by at least one or more spaces 
 * followed by any set of characters with exactly one preceding dot, 
 * then followed by at least one or more spaces followed by any set of characters and end of string
 */

 //Need the extended or basic because any version less than 4.9 doesn't fully support c++11 regular expressions (28.13).
 //The error is because creating a regex by default uses ECMAScript syntax for the expression, which doesn't support brackets.
const regex nameParser("^[a-zA-Z]+\\s+[a-zA-Z]\\.{1}\\s+[a-zA-Z]+$",regex::extended);
const regex anotherNameParser("[a-zA-Z]+",regex::extended);
const regex sampleParser("(abc)");

int main() {
    //simple regex testing
    string name = "bob R. Santiago";
    if(regex_match(name, nameParser)) {
        cout << "name is valid!" << endl;
    } else cout << "Error in valdiating name!" << endl;

    string anotherName = "Bobo";
    if(regex_match(anotherName, anotherNameParser)) {
            cout << "name is valid!" << endl;
    } else cout << "Error in valdiating name!" << endl;

    string sample = "abc";
    if(regex_match(sample, sampleParser)) {
            cout << "name is valid!" << endl;
    } else cout << "Error in valdiating name!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which version of g++? Some have known issues with their regex implementation.

Comment: I blame the purple background. ;)  Here is a good site for evaluating regular expressions.  http://regex101.com/  This may help you.

Comment: Like Wes alludes to, don't post an image when you can just paste the text. As an aside, you **really** should not run as admin.

Comment: You couldn't even make the error messages different? You've made your error output 33.3% as effective as it could be (at best).

Comment: @cdhowie I am using version 4.8.3

Comment: @Wes I wanted that ubuntu feel to it ;) and thanks for the site!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> //Need the extended or basic because gnu gcc-4.6.1 doesn't fully support c++11 regular expressions (28.13).
> ```

It doesn't support them *at all* until version 4.9, despite the presence of a `<regex>` header.

Sometimes it may appear to do what you want, but it basically doesn't.

**Upgrade to GCC 4.9.**

Answer (score 1):

Support for `<regex>` was not added until GCC 4.9. See the [release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html):

> Runtime Library (libstdc++)
>
> - Improved support for C++11, including:
>
>   - support for `<regex>`;